# How to filter by map an object array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that I want to filter to show only products with current kw. My code was worked perfect when it was just to one client, but know we want to compare many company's products and have to change something. My idea was to make an array for all clients and loop through them using an map method.

```
  {  ofertapompy.filter(person => {
          var  correctSize =  Math.ceil((`${calkowitezapotrzebowanie}`/1000));

           var i; 
    for(var i = 0; i <= person.pompy.length; i++ )
    {   
       if(correctSize >= 2 && correctSize <= 4.5) {return "3kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "1kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "2kw" in person.pompy[i].cena}
    if(correctSize === 4 ) {return "4kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "2kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "3kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 5 ) {return "5kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "4kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "3kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 6 ) {return "6kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "5kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "4kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 7) {return "7kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "6kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "5kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 8) {return "8kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "7kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "6kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 9) {return "9kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "8kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "7kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 10) {return "10kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "9kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "8kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 11) {return "11kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "10kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "9kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 12) {return "12kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "11kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "10kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 13) {return "13kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "12kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "11kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 14) {return "14kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "12kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "13kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 15) {return "15kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "14kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "13kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 16) {return "16kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "15kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "14kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 17) {return "17kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "16kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "15kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 18) {return "18kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "17kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "16kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 19) {return "18kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "17kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "19kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 20) {return "20kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "19kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "18kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 21) {return "21kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "20kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "19kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 22) {return "22kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "21kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "20kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 23) {return "23kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  || 
    "22kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "21kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize === 24) {return "24kw" in person.pompy[i].cena   || 
    "22kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "23kw" in person.pompy[i].cena} 
    if(correctSize => 25) {return "25kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "24kw" in person.pompy[i].cena || 
    "23kw" in person.pompy[i].cena  } 
    
   }}   ).map((filteredPerson, index) => {
   var dupa = index +1
   return(<>
   <tr style={{width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#ae4a84"}}>{filteredPerson.nazwa_firmy}</tr>
   <tr>this is {dupa}</tr>
   <tr> <td>
     { filteredPerson.pompy.forEach(name => {
  var dupa = name.find(name=> name.cena.key === "5kw" )
      return dupa}) }
     </td>
     <td>{ filteredPerson.pompy[0].gwarancja}</td>
     <Table  className={style.effectivetable} style={{boarderColor: "transparent"}} responsive  striped  hover ><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody>
  {  Object.entries(filteredPerson.pompy[0].cena).filter((
    [key])=> {
     var  correctSize =  Math.ceil((`${calkowitezapotrzebowanie}`/1000));
  
     if(correctSize === 3 ) {return  key == "3kw" || key == "2kw" || key == "1kw"}
     if(correctSize === 4 ) {return  key == "4kw"|| key == "2kw" || key == "3kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 5 ) {return  key == "5kw" || key == "3kw" || key == "4kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 6 ) {return  key == "6kw" || key == "4kw" || key == "5kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 7) {return  key == "7kw" || key == "6kw" || key == "5kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 8) {return  key == "8kw" || key == "6kw" || key == "7kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 9) {return  key == "9kw" || key == "8kw" || key == "7kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 10) {return  key == "10kw" || key == "8kw" || key == "9kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 11) {return  key == "11kw" || key == "10kw" || key == "9kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 12) {return  key == "12kw" || key == "10kw" || key == "11kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 13) {return  key == "13kw" || key == "12kw" || key == "11kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 14) {return  key == "14kw" || key == "12kw" || key == "13kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 15) {return  key == "15kw" || key == "14kw" || key == "13kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 16) {return  key == "16kw" || key == "14kw" || key == "15kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 17) {return  key == "17kw" || key == "16kw" || key == "15kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 18) {return  key == "18kw" || key == "17kw" || key == "16kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 19) {return  key == "18kw" || key == "18kw" || key == "17kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 20) {return  key == "20kw" || key == "18kw" || key == "19kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 21) {return  key == "21kw" || key == "20kw" || key == "19kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 22) {return  key == "22kw" || key == "20kw" || key == "21kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 23) {return  key == "23kw" || key == "22kw" || key == "21kw"} 
     if(correctSize === 24) {return  key == "24kw" || key == "22kw" || key == "23kw"} 
     if(correctSize => 25 ) {return   key == "25kw" || key == "24kw" || key == "23kw"} 
 
    }
    
 
    ).map(([key,value],index) => {
   return(  <><tr><td> {key}</td><td> {(value*1.1).toFixed(1)}zł netto</td>
   <td>{ (cenaPoDotacjiIuldze(((value*1.1)), wysokoscDotacji, stawkaPodatkuDochodowego)).toFixed(1)}</td>
 
    </tr></>)
   })
 }
```

when it is hardcoded `filteredPerson.pompy[0].cena` show result, but instead of number I loop through all arrays.

```
const ofertapompy = [
  {id: 0,
    nazwa_firmy: "Company One", 
    pompy: [
  {id: 0,
    name: "zero",
    description: "",
    cena: {
      "9kw": 34064,
      "12kw": 35386,
      "15kw": 37434,
      "18kw": 38492,
      "22kw": 38934,
    },
  },
  
  {id: 1,
    name: "one",
    description: "",
    cena: {
      "9kw": 11,
      "12kw": 22,
      "15kw": 33,
      "18kw": 44,
      "22kw": 55,
      "25kw": 66,
      "30kw": 77,
    },
  }},
{id: 0,
    nazwa_firmy: "Company One", 
    pompy: [
  {id: 0,
    name: "zero",
    description: "",
    cena: {
      "9kw": 34064,
      "12kw": 35386,
      "15kw": 37434,
      "18kw": 38492,
      "22kw": 38934,
    },
  },
  
  {id: 1,
    name: "one",
    description: "",
    cena: {
      "9kw": 11,
      "12kw": 22,
      "15kw": 33,
      "18kw": 44,
      "22kw": 55,
      "25kw": 66,
      "30kw": 77,
    },
  }}]
```

Comment: This code would benefit considerably from some kind of look-up table you can implement more procecurally.

Comment: You don't need to put in all these tests: https://jsfiddle.net/9ymqxhaw/

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I want you to know that you can simplify that huge chain of if-statements near the bottom of your first code snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/xha4w0pu/

Answer (score 0):

We need 3 loops: for persons, for pompy and for cena. At each level we filter using the same function `checkKw(correctSize, kw)`. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sinoussi-20e4hm?file=/src/App.js).

It is better to optimize the `checkKw` function beacause it will be called a lot.